# cannot import name 'InconsistentVersionWarning' from 'sklearn.exceptions'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to import sklearn, but i'm keeping receiving this error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/Users/matheusbrandaofreire/CEMIG/analises-watson-assistant/notebooks/0-65-ExperimentoWatsonAssistant.ipynb Célula 6 line 5
      3 import numpy; print("NumPy", numpy.__version__)
      4 import scipy; print("SciPy", scipy.__version__)
----> 5 import sklearn; print("Scikit-Learn", sklearn.__version__)

File ~/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/__init__.py:83
     69     # We are not importing the rest of scikit-learn during the build
     70     # process, as it may not be compiled yet
     71 else:
   (...)
     77     # later is linked to the OpenMP runtime to make it possible to introspect
     78     # it and importing it first would fail if the OpenMP dll cannot be found.
     79     from . import (
     80         __check_build,  # noqa: F401
     81         _distributor_init,  # noqa: F401
     82     )
---> 83     from .base import clone
     84     from .utils._show_versions import show_versions
     86     __all__ = [
     87         "calibration",
     88         "cluster",
   (...)
    129         "show_versions",
    130     ]

File ~/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/base.py:18
     16 from . import __version__
     17 from ._config import config_context, get_config
---> 18 from .exceptions import InconsistentVersionWarning
     19 from .utils import _IS_32BIT
     20 from .utils._estimator_html_repr import estimator_html_repr

ImportError: cannot import name 'InconsistentVersionWarning' from 'sklearn.exceptions' (/Users/matheusbrandaofreire/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/exceptions.py)
```

I was receiving an numPy version error too, but I change his version and this new error appear.

Comment: What is your `scikit-learn` version ?

Comment: version 1.3.2. .